# Field.choice. Haciendo que las opciones salgan dinámicamente con una llave foránea

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Estoy queriendo trabajar unos atributos en unos modelos bajo el tipo de campo [Field.choice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices)

El contexto de su modelo de datos es el siguiente:

Tengo el modelo/tabla `Patient` y el modelo/tabla `CorporalStructure` en donde este último se refiera a las diferentes partes del cuerpo, como el hombro, codo, antebrazo, etcétera.

De esta forma se tiene la siguiente relación en donde 1 paciente tiene muchas estructuras corporales. Al tener este tipo de relación, se genera un `ForeignKey` llamado `Patient_id` en la tabla `CorporalStructures`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto quiere decir que cada que quiero crear una estructura corporal debo decir a que paciente pertenece, cosa que no quiero acorde a como tengo concebido mi sistema.

Mi archivo corporal_structure/models.py es el siguiente:

```
from django.db import models
from metrics.models import Metric

# Create your models here.

class CorporalStructure(models.Model):

    CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICES = (
        ('Escápula',(
            ('elevación:40°','Elevación:40°'),
            ('Descenso:10°','Descenso:10°'),
            ('retracción:25°','Retracción:25°'),
            ('protracción:30°','Protracción:30°'),
          )
         ),
        ('Hombro',(
            ('flexión:150°-170°','Flexión:150°-170°'),
            ('extensión:40°','Extensión:40°'),
            ('abducción (separación):160° a 180°','Abducción (separación):160° a 180°'),
            ('adducción (acercamiento):20° a 40°','Aducción (acercamiento):20° a 40°'),
            ('rotación interna con hombro aducido (acercado a tórax):70°','Rotación interna con hombro aducido (acercado a tórax):70°'),
            ('rotación externa con hombro abducido a 90°:60°','Rotación externa con hombro abducido a 90°:60°'),
            ('rotación interna con hombro a 90° de abducción:70°','Rotación interna con hombro a 90° de abducción:70°'),
            ('rotación externa con hombro a 90° de abducción:90°','Rotación externa con hombro a 90° de abducción:90°'),
            ('movimiento de arco horizontal del hombro de afuera hacia adentro: de 40-50° posterior a 130-160° anterior','Movimiento de arco horizontal del hombro de afuera hacia adentro: de 40-50° posterior a 130-160° anterior'),
            ('*circunducción: sumatoria de los movimientos anteriores','Circunducción: sumatoria de los movimientos anteriores'),

           )
         ),
        ('Codo', (
            ('extensión','Extensión'),
            ('flexión', 'Flexión'),
           )
        ),
        ('Antebrazo', (
            ('supinación','Supinación'),
            ('Pronación', 'Pronación'),
           )
        ),
        ('Carpo', (
            ('flexión palmar','Flexión palmar'),
            ('flexión dorsal (o extensión)', 'Flexión dorsal (o extensión)'),
            ('desviación ulnar', 'Desviación ulnar'),
            ('desviación radial', 'Desviación radial'),
            ('*circunducción: sumatoria de los movimientos anteriores','Circunducción: sumatoria de los movimientos anteriores'),
         ),
        ),
        ('Mano', (
            ('aproximación interfalángica','Aproximación interfalángica'),
            ('separación interfalángica', 'Separación interfalángica'),
            ('flexión superficial de falanges (se puede hacer en masa, es decir las  5 falanges al tiempo, o de manera individual)', 'Flexión superficial de falanges (se puede hacer en masa, es decir las  5 falanges al tiempo, o de manera individual)'),
            ('flexión profunda de falanges (se puede hacer en masa, o de manera individual)', 'Flexión profunda de falanges (se puede hacer en masa, o de manera individual)'),
            ('flexión metacarpofalangica (se puede hacer en masa, o de manera individual)','Flexión metacarpofalangica (se puede hacer en masa, o de manera individual)'),
            ('extensión de las falanges (se puede hacer en masa o de manera individual)','Extensión de las falanges (se puede hacer en masa o de manera individual)'),
            ('separación del pulgar','Separación del pulgar'),
            ('aproximación del pulgar','Aproximación del pulgar'),
            ('oposición del pulgar','Oposición del pulgar'),
            ('flexión del pulgar','Flexión del pulgar'),
         ),
        ),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICES, blank=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    freedom_degrees = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Metric)
    patient = models.ForeignKey('userprofile.PatientProfile', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que cuando se vaya a crear un paciente en el modelo `Patient` en su formulario se le especifique que estructuras corporales van a examinarse de ese paciente, por lo que en el modelo Patient necesitaría un campo también de tipo Field.choice para ello, solo que sería ya llamar  a los objetos o instancias que han sido creadas en el modelo `CorporalStructures` en cuanto a su atributo `name` especificado anteriormente.

Sería algo asi como hacer un query o consulta al modelo CorporalStructure desde el modelo Patient y renderizar esos datos de `CorporalStructure.name` (por decir cualquier cosa) en un atributo de tipo Field.choice

Django [en la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.choices) lo plantea

> Note that choices can be any iterable object – not necessarily a list or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically. But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. choices is meant for static data that doesn’t change much, if ever.

Mi modelo Patient es este PatientProfile/models.py

```
class PatientProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    #active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICE =CorporalStructure.objects.all()
    corporal_structures = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICE, blank=False)


    partner_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    partner_phone = models.CharField(verbose_name=u'phone', max_length=25, blank=True)
    care_provider = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
```

Cuando agregué este campo al modelo PatientProfile

```
CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICE =CorporalStructure.objects.all()
        corporal_structures = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICE, blank=False)
```

Me aparece este error

django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

```
ERRORS:
userprofile.PatientProfile.corporal_structures: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.
```

Y entiendo un poco lo que sucede, ya que el atributo `corporal_structures` al ponerle su propiedad de `choices`, espera es una lista o tupla o cualquier elemento sobre el cual se pueda iterar y yo lo que le estoy es pasando es el resultado de una consulta tipo ORM, que son los datos que guarde en mi modelo `CorporalStructures` anteriormente.

```
CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICE =CorporalStructure.objects.all()
corporal_structures = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICE, blank=False)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo unas dudas también en relación a a concepción de como he pensado las relaciones entre los modelos `Patient` y `CorporalStructure` y son:

Yo quiero que cuando guarde un registro de un paciente, pueda seleccionar las estructuras corporales que le trataran a dicho paciente. 
La lógica básica me dice que 1 paciente tiene muchas estructuras corporales, pero al ponerseme el `Patient_id` como llave foránea en la tabla CorporalStructures, lo que me sale es que cada que voy a crear una estructura corporal debo elegir al paciente al que pertenece, de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando lo que deseo es poder detallar el campo Field.choice (sus multiples opciones) es decir de esta forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en el formulario del modelo de PatientProfile.

¿De que manera puedo lograr lo que me propongo?

Sé que esta inquietud es más de diseño ...
¿Necesito una llave foránea de `CorporalStructure` en `PatientProfile` o se puede llamar de manera simple la información de las múltiples opciones del Field.choice sin necesidad de una F.K?

Cabe aclarar que los formularios sobre los cuales verifico esto son en el admin de django.

Cualquier orientación será apreciada.

Comment: Tengo una pregunta offtopic, con que haces las gráficas para representar los modelos?

Comment: Hola Javier, la herramienta es MySQL workbench con su funcionalidad de Visual Database Design https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo (puedo estar equivocado) que el problema puede originarse en el modelado. Un paciente puede tener varias estructuras corporales, pero también es cierto que una estructura corporal puede "pertenecer" o estar compartida por varios pacientes. Es decir, tienes una relación **N-N**, no **1-N**.

Yo reconvertiría el modelo "Estructura corporal" a "Tipo de Estructura Corporal". Los datos que has puesto en la variable `CORPORAL_STRUCTURE_CHOICES`
debería ir como datos de la base de datos, no en una variable. Esto te permite, además, añadir nuevos "tipos de estructuras corporales", llegado el caso, sin necesidad de asignárselas a ningún paciente.

Para guardar los datos concretos de cada paciente necesitaras una tercera tabla, una tabla intermedia que simplemente guarda claves foráneas a "paciente" y a "tipo de estructura corporal", así como el resto de los datos que necesitas asociar con ese paciente y esa extremidad

Por ejemplo, para almacenar que "menganito" (id_paciente **21**) tiene **40º** de los extensión del hombro (id_extensión **23**), hay que crear un registro en la nueva tabla con los datos `(paciente_id=21, tipo_extremidad_id=23, valor=40)`.

Comment: Los atributos como ``type`` o ``metrics``, sobre los que no digo nada, deberían ir en o en la tabla de "Tipo de Estructura Corporal" o en la nueva tabla intermedia, según su naturaleza. Como no sé nada del dominio no me mojo :-)

Comment: N-N es ManyToMany ¿verdad? De esta forma lo pensé, solo que en mi análisis de modelado, habia dimensionado que si un paciente tiene muchas estructuras corporales, serviría para cada instancia de paciente que las tendrá, y cada estructura corporal perteneceria a una instancia asi por cada instancia tendria varias ...

Comment: Es correcto el acercamiento de tener una relación N to N entre estos dos modelos. De esta manera me aseguro que puedo tener el campo de estructuras corporales (brazos, manos, dedos, etc,) en el modelo paciente. Y por transitividad con quien se relacione, tendría acceso a éstas.

Comment: como puedo consultar los pacientes que tienen determinadas estructuras corporales teniendo en cuenta que ¿ya hay una relación de ManyTo Many entre estas dos tablas? Tengo un paciente con id_81 que tiene el corporal_structure_id de 3 Quisiera saber todos los pacientes que tienen asociada la corporal_structure de id de 3. NO tengo claro como hacer la consulta

Comment: > Quisiera saber todos los pacientes que tienen asociada la corporal_structure de id de 3. NO tengo claro como hacer la consulta

Comment: > Quisiera saber todos los pacientes que tienen asociada la corporal_structure de id de 3. NO tengo claro como hacer la consulta

La consulta tendrías que hacerla contra la tabla intermedia, haciendo un join de dicha tabla con la tabla de pacientes. Cuando haces una relacion N-N a MonyToMany django crea por ti esa tabla intermedia, pero en este caso creo recomendable crearla tu mismo.

Comment: Por ejemplo, creando un modelo ``Dolencias``, con claves foraneas a ``Paciente`` y a ``TipoEstructuraCorporal``, con::

    ``Dolencias.objects.filter(estructura_corporal_id=3)``

tendrías todas las dolencias que necesitas. podrías obtener los pacientes usando, por ejemplo::

    ``[p.paciente for p in Dolencias.objects.filter(estructura_corporal_id=3)]``